# error in running imported github java eyetracking project

Tags: java

I imported an eye tracking project from [this site](https://github.com/EyeTribe/tet-java-client).  I don't know which is the main file, so I am not able to run this project. When I am trying to run all the files present in the source folder, I get an error like this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Can you please help me to find out main file in this project and how to run this project?

Answer (score 0):

Its an API you can use it in you project.
There is no such class or method called main.

This is Java API of project, please look into it. 
http://eyetribe.github.io/tet-java-client/

Comment: so what i am suppose to do.??..i wanted to know what is output after running this code..and if its API then i have to create my own code???

Comment: yes you have to create your own project and after that you can consume these api calls in your project.

Comment: i send you that site name can you please go through it and could you please tell me how i will create my own code.if please help me to find out this problem its very urgent.

Comment: the eye tribe.com and i am sending you gits site also from where you can get code in any language (c++,c#,java) https://github.com/eyetribe